# How can I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 but have my PC boot into windows without prompting me at start up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I want to be able to put Ubuntu on a spare Hard Drive of mine while still primarily booting from Windows 10 on my SSD however I would like to be able to boot straight into Windows by default without going through grub. But I would still like the option if i turned on the pc to say hold down a key and then it give me a boot menu, is this in any possible?

Thanks

Comment: Pilot6's answer will work. However, you won't be able to just hold down a key to boot into Ubuntu, you'll have to use the BIOS boot menu. The only way you can really do this easily is by installing both OSes to a single drive and editing the GRUB config file to make it so it doesn't show and auto-boots into Windows. You could then hold `Shift` while booting to bring up the menu and choose Ubuntu from there.

Comment: For this, you would have to install Windows 10 first. Manually assign a partition for windows10 and install it. Then afterwards, on another partition, install Ubuntu. After that you need to configure Grub. When you are done installing both the OS's, then post a question about Grub, no one can help you this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to do. You can install Ubuntu to HDD and install grub there.

Then set SSD as the first boot device in bios.

Then you will be able to use your bios boot menu to boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: Simply take an usb-harddisk for this and install Ubuntu completely with grub on to this usb-harddisk - thats all. Plug-in and use Ubuntu whenever you want and normal PC / Laptop then for Windows A (10 is hexadecimal an A - but A is patented by Bertelsmann with Google ... )